# $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log n}}$ convergent $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log(\log n)}}$ divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am preparing for my exam and need help with the following taks:

1. Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log n}}$ converges. (Hint: $\int_{n=\log 2}^{\infty} \frac{e^x}{x^x}dx$ exists)

This is my solution. Since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log n}}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(e^{\log(\log n)})^{\log n}}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(e^{\log n\log(\log n)})}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n^{\log(\log n)})}<\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ (for large n). Since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ is converging, thus our series converges. Is this proof correct? But how do we proof this with help of the hint?

2. Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log(\log n)}}$ is divergent.

First of all, I have one problem. How am I able to see very easily if a series converges or diverges. I mean in this task, we are getting told what to show. But often we have to find it out ourselves. And since I can't decide straight away, if a series converges/diverges, I don't know if I should search for a series bigger or smaller than our series and therefore am losing lots of time. Does anyone have any tips for me?

After a long time of thinking I've got this idea. $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log(\log n)}}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(e^{\log(\log n)})^{\log(\log n)}}=$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\log(\log n)\cdot\log(\log n)}}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log(n))^2}$. And then I realized that we proved in the previous task that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\log(n))^{-k}$ diverges for $k\geq 1$. So I can refer to this result right? Is this proof correct?

Comment: Your argument for the divergence of $\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log(\log n)}}$ claims that $(\log n)^{\log(\log n)} = (\log n)^2$, which is incorrect.

Comment: For the divergence, it's easiest to compare to $\sum \frac{1}{n}$, which diverges -- note that $(\log n)^{\log\log n}=e^{(\log\log n)^2}\leq e^{\log n}=n$ for large $n$.

Comment: As a general tip, remember that $\sum\frac{1}{n^p}$ diverges for $p\leq 1$ and converges for $p>1$. Many convergence/divergence questions can be answered by finding a way to compare to one of these simple series.

Comment: @ThomasBloom Thank you for your answers. But why is $(\log(\log n))^2$ $\leq$ $\log(\log n)$. I mean it seems to be right, but like I would never have thought about that because my intitution would say that $(\log(\log n))^2$ $\geq$ $\log(\log(n)$ which is wrong...but why?

Comment: It is not true that loglog^2 \leq loglog. What is true is that loglog^2 \leq log. This is true just as log(X)^2 \leq X, for large X.

Comment: @ThomasBloom Ah now I see. Thanks. Any idea how to solve part one with help of the hint?

Comment: Use integral test and substitute $\log x = t$.

Comment: @ajr I then have dx= x dt and $\int \frac{x}{t^t}dt$ and don't know how to solve this.

Comment: $x=e^t$ and you get the hint exactly. Though to show that the hint is in fact true, you need to do a procedure similar to what you've done for the series.

Comment: @ajr Can I ignore this lower bound of $\log(2)$? I mean we know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^t}{t^t}$ converges iff $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{1}^{n+1} \frac{e^x}{x^x} dx$ exists : Applying the root test, we get |x|<1 so the series is absolute convergent and $\int_{1}^{n+1} \frac{e^x}{x^x} dx$ exists. Thus the series converges. Where does the lower bound of the integral $(\log(2)$ come from?